# php & wordpress ASC / DESC using href AND sorting

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been battling with trying to get this code working on my site.
I would like to have the ability for the user to sort posts in ascending or descending order from clicking href link.
This option should be remembered when the user then chooses to sort the post list by another option e.g. title, votes, date.

Here is what I have got far:

```
<?php $sort= $_GET['sort'];
if($sort == "A")
{
$order= "gdsr_sort=thumbs";
}
if($sort == "B")
{
$order= "orderby=title";
}
if($sort == "C")
{
$order= "orderby=date";
}
?>

<?php $updown= $_GET['updown'];

if($updown == "Y")
{$ascend= "ASC";} //this orders in ascending
if($updown == "Z")
{$ascend= "DESC";} //this orders in descending
?>

<a href="?sort=A&updown=<?php echo $updown?>">Thumbs</a>
<a href="?sort=B&updown=<?php echo $updown?>">Author</a>
<a href="?sort=C&updown=<?php echo $updown?>">Date</a>

<?php $sort= isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : "B";

?>
<a href="?updown=Y&sort=<?php echo $sort?>">Ascending</a>
<a href="?updown=Z&sort=<?php echo $sort?>">Descending</a>

<?php query_posts($order.'&order=$.ascend.'); ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

The href for sorting works just fine however the ASC / DESC do not do anything the whole thing just stays DESC.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using confusing letters, I can suggest 2 better solutions:

1. Use a base-3 number (`1021021210`) to determine which fields are not sorted (0), ASC (1) or DESC (2).
2. Use PHP's `$_GET` superglobal and create URLs such as `example.com/index.php?fielda=asc&fieldb=desc`.
   Then parse it to see what the user wanted to sort.

Solution 2 is preferred.

Comment: I dont know what using the base-3 number would involve?!

http://www.something.com/?updown=1&sort=A

i am using $_GET for the URL do you mean have asc and desc within the URL?

Thanks for your help

Comment: it indicates the state of the fields in places 1, 2, 3, etc where 0 is not sorted, 1 is ASC and 2 is DESC, you can parse the string you get and determine which fields are sorted how, the second solution is better though.

Comment: I'll admit i'm a little out of my depth here, 
Can you help me with a example?

Simon

Comment: You should really be using solution number 2, it's much better, solution 1 is if the GET is already occupied by something else.

Answer (score 0):

Way too complicated. Just store The user ASC/DESC preference in a Cookie (via JS, if you prefer a quick&dirty solution), use The Cookie Value for Setting Order when sorting.

Comment: do you have a example of how i could do this please wildrot?

Thanks for repling
simon